# Как сделать, чтобы если переменная изменялась, то программа что-нибудь делала

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно чтобы если переменная изменялась(я делаю парсер статей в группе вк), то программа что-нибудь выполняла например просто:
`print("переменная изменилась! ")`  и чтобы это выполнялось только когда переменная хотя-бы немного изменилась

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447397/how-to-check-if-a-variables-value-has-changed

Comment: Допустим нужно отследить переменную x_var. Заводим еще одну переменную prevous, присваиваем ей значение x_var. Потом создаем бесконечный цикл, в котором сравниваем x_var и prevous. Если они не равны выводим сообщение, или что там нужно, и снова присваеваем prevous значение x_var

Comment: Можете потратить на меня своё время и написать выше вами описанный код. Допустим x_var будет через input. Спасибо! (если у вас правда есть время)

Comment: Что тут не так:     while True:
 x_var = input()
 prevous = x_var

 if x_var != prevous:
  print("Переменная изменилась")

Answer (score 0):

В вашем тексте не так последовательность операторов. Должно быть:

```
import copy
previous="ххх"
s=copy.deepcopy(previous)
while s!='zzz': 
    s= input() 
    if s != previous: 
       print("Переменная изменилась") 
    if s == 'xxx':
        break
    previous = copy.deepcopy(s)
```

Результат

```
ttt
Переменная изменилась   
yyy
Переменная изменилась    
yyy    
zzz
Переменная изменилась
```

Вместо deepcopy можно, конечно пользовать срезы `(s=previous[:] и previous = s[:])`, но так вы лучше разберетесь с поверхностными и глубокими копями.

Comment: Не работает, не находит prevous Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vladislav\Desktop\prog\python\my3.py", line 3, in <module>
    if x_var != prevous:
NameError: name 'prevous' is not defined

Comment: Исправил. Теперь все работает

Comment: @Vlad_superproger ну как, получилось?

Comment: Вот не пойму, за что мне этот ответ так лихо заминусовали?